# Extruding a form along a curve + rotating it

Tags: extrude, bezier-curves

**Is there a way to control the rotation of the extruded mesh along the curve?**

To show what I want to do: [image]

And this is what I got so far
[image]

Don't worry about the overall proportions and the mat (still on it) **But my Problem is that I can't control the rotation of the object along the curve.**

I tried to apply the modifiers and just rotate parts of the model by hand, but that leads to certain issues in the edgeflow and I can imagine that there is a much easier and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rotate the vertice of a bezier curve: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>, you can also see and change the *Tilt* value in the 3D properties panel (activated with <kbd>N</kbd>) on the  right of the 3D View. <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to come back to its previous value.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you so much. Thats exactly what I have ooked for =) Thank you so much. You probably saved me 2 or 3 working hours.